# Open modal on function call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-modal

I have an js file with a function Example. I'm calling that function in another func bellow. What I need right now is to have my modal opened without button clicked. It works perfectly on button clicked, but its not what i need in my situation. Any solution how can I display this modal on function call without clicking on this button?

```
function Example() {

  return (
    <>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
      <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              ...
      </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: could you share whole code of your task?

Comment: you could open modal on componentDidMount, like 

`componentDidMount() {
  openModal();
}`

Comment: use $("#exampleModal").modal('show'); in your function where you want it to be opened.
For more details refer: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#methods

Comment: When I use $("#exampleModal").modal('show') i get "Failed to compile" $ is not defined. Any suggestion?

Comment: Use import $ from 'jquery'; in your code. Make sure you have installed jquery dependancy

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#exampleModal").modal('show');
```

Try calling this in a function which shows the modal. Also don't forget to import . jquery before calling this function. You can import jquery in main page and all will work fine

Comment: Why to use jQuery in react at all ? You can very well manage it by react

Comment: @Learner yes you can. Also the category here for this question is in react but he/she doesn't seem to be using react here, i mean the use of state and other things and also using bootstrap so I gave answer through jQuery way. 

Comment: First of all, not sure what do you mean by `he/she doesn't seem to be using react here`, the code OP posted is a function component of React, states are only defined in the main component, not in sub components and its clear that the OP is using  `<Example>` as a sub component for modal and as far as bootstrap is concerned, it can be used with react, if someone uses bootstrap, it doesnt mean by default they use jquery. Anyways, I am not saying your answer is wrong but its not the right way, thats all.

Answer (score 1):

Just define a state variable, lets call it `showModal`, initialize it with `false` and then in your code show or hide modal based upon `showModal` is `true` or `false`.

That way when you want to show it "manually", all you need to do is toggle that `showModal` to `true` like so:

```
this.setState({showModal: true});
```

You need some knowledge of react in order to understand my answer though :)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem by using React Hooks. Thank you for replies. Happy hacking :)

```js
function Example() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true);

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  return (
    <>
      <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Close
          </Button>
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Save Changes
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yup, same thing which I have proposed, glad to see you made it work